# How to include both "latest" and "JSON with specific Offset" in "startingOffsets" while importing data from Kafka into Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a streaming query saving data into filesink. I am using .option("startingOffsets", "latest") and a checkpoint location. If there is any down time on Spark and when the streaming query starts again i do not want to start processing where the query left off when it went down rather than this scenario i would also like to add ("startingOffsets", """ {"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1},"topicB":{"0":-2}} """) by specifying the user defined offset which needs to process from.

i tried doing this with different programs but i need to achieve this in one single program

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger

object OSB_offset_kafkaToSpark {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.
      builder().
      appName("OSB_kafkaToSpark").
      config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://somemongodb.com:27018").
      getOrCreate()

    println("SparkSession -> "+spark)

    import spark.implicits._

    val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "somekafkabroker:9092, somekafkabroker:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "someTopic")
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("startingOffsets",""" {"someTopic":{"0":438521}}, "someTopic":{"1":438705}}, "someTopic":{"2":254180}}""")
      .option("endingOffsets",""" {"someTopic":{"0":-1}}, "someTopic":{"1":-1}}, "someTopic":{"2":-1}} """)
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
      .load()
    val dfs = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

    val data = dfs.withColumn("splitted", split($"value", "/"))
      .select($"splitted".getItem(4).alias("region"), $"splitted".getItem(5).alias("service"), col("value"))
      .withColumn("service_type", regexp_extract($"service", """.*(Inbound|Outbound|Outound).*""", 1))
      .withColumn("region_type", concat(
        when(col("region").isNotNull, col("region")).otherwise(lit("null")), lit(" "),
        when(col("service").isNotNull, col("service_type")).otherwise(lit("null"))))
      .withColumn("datetime", regexp_extract($"value", """\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d""", 0))

    val extractedDF = data.filter(
      col("region").isNotNull &&
        col("service").isNotNull &&
        col("value").isNotNull &&
        col("service_type").isNotNull &&
        col("region_type").isNotNull &&
        col("datetime").isNotNull)
      .filter("region != ''")
      .filter("service != ''")
      .filter("value != ''")
      .filter("service_type != ''")
      .filter("region_type != ''")
      .filter("datetime != ''")

    val pathstring = "/user/spark_streaming".concat(args(0))


    val query = extractedDF.writeStream
      .format("json")
      .option("path", pathstring)
      .option("checkpointLocation", "/user/some_checkpoint")
      .outputMode("append")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

I need run a single program with both .option("startingOffsets", "latest") and .option("startingOffsets",""" {"someTopic":{"0":438521}}, "someTopic":{"1":438705}}, "someTopic":{"2":254180}}""").

I am not sure if this is achievable

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question at this point, so the OP likely got their answer, but when specifying offsets in JSON string format, you can use -2 for earliest and -1 for latest.

[src](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

> The start point when a query is started, either "earliest" which is from the earliest offsets, "latest" which is just from the latest offsets, or a json string specifying a starting offset for each TopicPartition. **In the json, -2 as an offset can be used to refer to earliest, -1 to latest.** Note: For batch queries, latest (either implicitly or by using -1 in json) is not allowed. For streaming queries, this only applies when a new query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off. Newly discovered partitions during a query will start at earliest.